# How to pass multiple data to controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, api

These are two select box. When i select both product and warranty value then it should pass to the controller.So how should i pass ?

```
<select id="products">
    <option value="1">Mobile</option>
     <option value="2">Laptop</option>
</select>

<select id="warrant">
    <option value="1">1 Years</option>
     <option value="2">2 years</option>
     <option value="3">3 years</option>
</select>
```

This is my Script file

```
$('#products').change(function () {
     var product_id=$(this).val();
})
$('#warrant').change(function () {
     var warrant_id=$(this).val();
})
```

I want to pass those warrant_id and product_id in Controller in below Code So How can i pass ?

```
<script>
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/productChart'+{
  warrant_id,product_id
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
            this.sales = data.sales;
            this.start = data.start;
            this.to = data.end;
        });
 </script>
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/productChart','Controller@productChart');
```

Comment: its not passing both at the moment ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
nope i was just trying.But how can i ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send / pass your `variable` data to your backend in post request using `fetch` API.

Define both the `variable` (product_id / warrant_id) as global to be accessible and assign their value back to the variables and then use `formData.append` method to add `data` to your `formData` to be able to send it your laravel `backend`.

Also, if you have more `data` to send you can simply `append` more values to your `formData`.

```js
var product_id
var warrant_id

$('#products').change(function() {
  product_id = $(this).val();
})
$('#warrant').change(function() {
  warrant_id = $(this).val();
})

function callFetch() {
  var formData = new FormData(); //initialize form Data
  formData.append('product_id', product_id); //append product_id
  formData.append('warrant_id', warrant_id);//append warrant_id

  //Post Request
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/productChart', {
      body: formData,
      method: "post"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      //do something with data
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="products">
  <option value="1">Mobile</option>
  <option value="2">Laptop</option>
</select>

<select id="warrant">
  <option value="1">1 Years</option>
  <option value="2">2 years</option>
  <option value="3">3 years</option>
</select>

<button onclick="callFetch()">
 Post Data
</button>
```

Comment: So Can i put method get instead of post ?

Comment: @SauravShrestha NO ! Post method is meant to posting data not getting.

Comment: @SauravShrestha Really. You need to make sure you are copying the exact i have provided above. Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jrgae527/1/ - check the network console it is sending the data.

Comment: @SauravShrestha here is a working screenshot - data is being sent: https://ibb.co/87Rr8cG

Comment: Okay ..Bro .. I need to ask you but

Comment: @SauravShrestha what is it you want to ask ?

Comment: You have any social media .So i can share you my some screenshot.
its just problem i am struck in.so

Comment: @SauravShrestha According to stackoverflow guideline we can not share these details publicbly. Let me know if the problem is related to this - i will be happy to help or else you can post another question with your specific problem :) i hope you are understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764571/uncaught-in-promise-referenceerror-sales-is-not-defined-at-drawchart.      
can You look please ?

Comment: @SauravShrestha Any reason for unaccepting the answer ? Please let me know :)

Comment: but it didnot work because. my route is to get a method so I cannot use 
  post method. below down code worked for me
I am really sorry

Comment: @SauravShrestha  you are upvotting your own questions - you created a second account to do that. Its wrong to do that