# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: sales is not defined at drawChart

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts, google-visualization

This is for

```
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/salesChart')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.sales = data.sales;
             console.log(sales);
         });
```

Google CHart Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    sales[0].forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
        if(element === "Month")
            data.addColumn('string', element);
        else
            data.addColumn('number', element);
    });
    sales.splice(0,1)
    data.addRows(sales)
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title:'Sales Chart'+ '('+ start +'-'+to + ')'
        },
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        vAxis:{title: 'Quantity (MT)',viewWindow: {min: 0},format:'# MT'},
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

But when id console.log(sales) Below images data will come like this.and sometimes graph will come and sometimes throws errors

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: You have not defined sales anywhere in your code  but your are trying to access it in your `chart`

Comment: I have send  variable sales  from controller.
and When i  do console.log(sales).data will come like in above picture.
sometimes chart will plot .When i do refresh again like 2 time then error occur.
and i have defined sales as this.sales = data.sales;

Comment: You should read up on the [documentation for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both google's `load` method and the `fetch` method run asynchronously,
so you have to wait until both have completed before trying to draw the chart.

you could use something similar to the following...

load google charts, then fetch the data, then draw the chart...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['line']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  var options = {
      chart: {
          title:'Sales Chart'+ '('+ start +'-'+to + ')'
      },
      width: 600,
      height: 500,
      vAxis:{title: 'Quantity (MT)',viewWindow: {min: 0},format:'# MT'},
  };

  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/salesChart')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.sales[0].forEach(element => {
        if(element === "Month")
            dataTable.addColumn('string', element);
        else
            dataTable.addColumn('number', element);
    });
    data.sales.splice(0,1)
    dataTable.addRows(data.sales)

    chart.draw(dataTable, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
  });
});
```